# OP removing question after answer selected

Tags: discussion

I've just answered [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014735/getting-syntax-error-using-jquery).  After accepting the answer, the OP then changed his question to another problem - which I know I shouldn't have answered (I should have requested as new question) but I updated my answer anyway.

The OP has now edited his question to remove the essence of either the original or new problem, and instead has a statement saying that the problem has been fixed.

What is the correct thing to do here?  Roll the question back so it's in its original state? Roll it back to the "new problem" state? Leave it and let him continue to get downvoted and/or closed by people who didn't see the original question?

Comment: I would roll it back... but I don't know which version is the correct one!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [current version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13014735/8) of the question is beyond silly:

> Thanks Now i have got resolved..
>
> Thanks a lot for trying to help me out! :)

You should:

1. Rollback to the last revision that makes sense.

   Since yours is the only answer, feel free to chose the revision that mostly matches your answer.
2. Post a comment explaining to him that the question is already "marked resolved".

   Tell him that continuously changing the question invalidates current answers, and that we already know that your answer fixed his problem as he accepted it. Explain to him that we expect the question to be at the best shape possible, and discoverable by anyone else that might have the same problem.

   Perhaps you could just point him to this Meta question, so you won't have to write all of the above again.
3. If he edits it again, you should flag for moderation attention and explain the situation.

   Do not get into an edit war, if he continues being silly about it, a moderator can and most probably will lock the question.

Comment: Thanks Yannis, good advise, which I have followed the first two... fingers crossed I don't need to follow item 3 :-)

Comment: @freefaller A mod already locked the question and pointed him to this discussion, so you've successfully skipped #3 (this time ;)

Comment: Ah, excellent :-)  Thanks Yannis, and thanks George for locking it

Comment: Unfortunately #3 came into effect... the OP changed the question yet again this morning. I flagged it, and a mod has (as you predicted) locked the question - as well as rolling it back again

Comment: Oh, and just to add to the party, he's decided to register a [new user account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1768349/jim) to ask [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030759/)